# Perl subroutine local global issue

Tags: perl, scope, subroutine

For this tiny code, it always prints the values of @x in the Global block of code. How to issue an warning if I accidentally don't initialize a variable inside a subroutine without 'my @x'. I wan't a local variable in the subroutine as @x.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @x=qw/1 2 3/;

&mysub();

sub mysub{

    print "@x";
}
```

Comment: I don't agree with the close vote. This is not unclear. It's just unpossible I'm afraid.

Comment: Perl6 can do it, though. [This](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2014/12/10/day-10-introspecting-the-symbol-tables/) looks pretty neat.

Comment: Please don't call subroutines using `&`. It's never necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With regular Perl you cannot do that. The solution is **not to reuse the same variable names** in smaller scopes.

---

If you want to enforce this programmatically, you can use [Perl::Critic](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic). The policy [Perl::Critic::Policy::Variables::ProhibitReusedNames](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::Variables::ProhibitReusedNames) tells you if you have reused variable names that are already defined in an outer scope.

Comment: I agree, but very common variable names, like $t, $n, $count etc can creep in accidentally.  Is there any way or module to check it up?

Comment: Don't use single letter variable names. Get in to the habit of using narrowest scope you can. (E.g. current code block only if at all possible).

Comment: It pleases me that you call Perl5 "regular" and thus Perl6 implicitly "irregular". I'm sure that wasn't your intention but I agree anyhow. :-)

Comment: @PerlDog they are different languages. When I wrote the answer, I was convinced there is some way to do this with XS, and there is probably some module out there (or more likely it's in core anyway) that can do introspection up to a point where it can tell you about your scope. But I wasn't sure. Since we try to be on the spot here, I added a disclaimer. That's why I said _regular Perl_, as opposed to dark, arcane magic. I added the comment about Perl6 later, when I researched that arcane magic. Once I found that one, I gave up though. I see what you mean though. Perl6 can be weird, but fun :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Organize your code better.

   ```
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   sub mysub{
       print "@x";
   }

   {
       my @x=qw/1 2 3/;
       mysub();
   }
   ```

   By properly localizing variables, there's no change of accidentally referring to the wrong one.
2. Don't use such meaningless variable names.

   There's little chance of accessing `@frobs_by_name` by accident.